# automation for desktop applications Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, desktop-application, pywinauto

i am trying to automate desktop apps, i worked with PywinAuto it worked well for some but doesnt work well with chromium apps or thats what i think.

after executing

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application(backend='uia').start(r'C:\Program Files\Avast Software\Avast\AvastUI.exe').connect(title='Avast Free Antivirus', timeout=10)
app.AvastFreeAntivirus.print_control_identifiers()
```

all i got was

```
Control Identifiers:

Dialog - 'Avast Free Antivirus'    (L874, T69, R1884, B743)
['Dialog', 'Avast Free AntivirusDialog', 'Avast Free Antivirus']
child_window(title="Avast Free Antivirus", control_type="Window")
   | 
   | Pane - 'AvastChromiumWindow'    (L874, T69, R1884, B743)
   | ['Pane', 'AvastChromiumWindow', 'AvastChromiumWindowPane', 'Pane0', 'Pane1']
   | child_window(title="AvastChromiumWindow", control_type="Pane")
   |    | 
   |    | Pane - ''    (L874, T69, R1884, B743)
   |    | ['Pane2']
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Pane - 'Chrome Legacy Window'    (L874, T69, R1884, B743)
   |    |    | ['Pane3', 'Chrome Legacy Window', 'Chrome Legacy WindowPane']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Chrome Legacy Window", auto_id="3135776", control_type="Pane")

Process finished with exit code 0
```

so since this is a 'Chromium Window' is there a way to use selenium to handle this.
if there is a way to connect selenium with localhost that the app is running on